# ctrl+x/c/p (cut/copy/paste) subsitutes in Unix bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I can't find any documentation that shows the equivalents for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (cut/copy/paste) in Unix (and some other equivalents but these are more than enough to start with).

Comment: I tend to run in `screen` and use its capabilities to copy (control[ and control ]). Not what you asked and not an answer, but still potentially useful for you.

Comment: There is no good answer, because it depends on the terminal you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNOME Terminal is a terminal emulation application which is able to access a UNIX shell in the GNOME environment used in many Linux distributions.

**gnome-terminal keyboard shortcuts**
<sup>(partial list)</sup>

```
Key                   Action    
Shift+Ctrl+t          new tab    
Shift+Ctrl+w          close tab  
Shift+Ctrl+n          new window     
Ctrl+{PgUp,PgDown}    change tabs    
Ctrl+Insert           copy selection to clipboard   
Shift+Ctrl+c          copy selection to clipboard    
Shift+Ctrl+v          paste from clipboard  
Click middle button   paste from clipboard using the mouse 
Ctrl+Click            Open URL under mouse cursor
```

To extend a selected region that was selected with the mouse, hold the Shift key while clicking.

A list of gnome-terminal keyboard shortcuts including additional keyboard shortcuts can be accessed in the gnome-terminal by selecting *Edit* -> *Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` and other shells, keys and control/escape sequences are bound to a large number of editing behaviours, including a cut & paste equivalent, although to my knowledge, it's only on a line-by-line (and command line history) basis:   The prompts and other screen data aren't manipulated with these tools.

There are hundreds of key bindings.  In `bash` their mappings can be viewed with `bind -p`. `tcsh` uses `bindkey` for the same, and uses slightly different notation. Terminology is different, however, from how one would describe the acts of selecting, cutting, and pasting in a GUI.  I'll try to translate a few of the important terms:

- **kill** or **delete** -- cuts text from the screen and places it in the clipboard.
- **yank** -- copies the clipboard to the screen at the cursor.
- **mark** -- sets the start of a selection, or refers to the start of a selection.
- **point** -- the cursor, or insertion point for copied text.
- **region** -- the selected text between the **mark** and **point**.

Unfortunately, (to my knowledge), only the **point** is visible, as the cursor.  The **mark** and **region** are not highlighted by default.

In `bash`'s `bind -p` output, `\C` stands for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and `\e` stands for <kbd>esc</kbd>.

I couldn't possibly cover the entire breadth of editing key bindings, but I'll give a couple to get you started:

- `"\C-k": kill-line`   <kbd>ctrl-k</kbd>  cut text from the cursor to end-of-line into the clipboard.
- `"\C-y": yank`  <kbd>ctrl-y</kbd> copy the clipboard to screen at cursor.

As I said, there are hundreds of bindings.  They may refer to regions, lines, words, or characters, and some key sequences are so ponderous that it's often just easier to retype what needs to be copied than to use the combinations.  However, I do find that <kbd>ctrl-k</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-y</kbd> accomplish the majority of my cutting and pasting needs.

There is also a plethora of information on the web about "unix key bindings" that you may find useful for your purposes.